# How to retrieve associated list name from a FieldLookupValue Sharepoint 2013 CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I need to retrieve some information from a FieldLookupValue using CSOM SharePoint2013 library.
Specifically, I have a SPList and I need to populate a Field which type is Lookup. Is there a way to know the name of associated list? I know for sure that this information is contained in the FieldLookupvalue: if I create an instance of it using LookupID of associated Item SharePoint automatically associates the lists. Infact this code works well:

```
        switch (field.TypeAsString)
        {
            case "Lookup":
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(info);
                FieldLookupValue lv = new FieldLookupValue() { LookupId = id };
                newItem[field.InternalName] = lv;
                break; 
            default:
                // do nothing
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

[FieldLookupValue class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldlookupvalue(v=office.15).aspx) does not expose any properties for getting associated list, but you could retrieve the associated list from a [Lookup field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldlookup%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve associated List for `Predecessors` field from `Tasks` list:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");
     var field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Predecessors");
     var lookupField = ctx.CastTo<FieldLookup>(field);
     ctx.Load(lookupField);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     var lookupListId = new Guid(lookupField.LookupList); //returns associated list id
     //Retrieve associated List
     var lookupList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetById(lookupListId);
     ctx.Load(lookupList);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: I'm going to upvote you since you put me exactly where I needed to be.  However, in my environment, lookupField.LookupList was a string, specifically the list Title.